# CodeIgniter Language Class Library Not Working

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multilingual

I build a website with CodeIgniter 3.1.3 and I want my website have multipe languages, so I tried using language library for the first time by following CI official guide & tutorial from other web, but it's not working as expected.

My `application/language/english/slogan_lang.php`:

```
$lang["slogan1"] = "A little social media but with more fun!",
$lang["slogan2"] = "Where face and real name is not important.",
$lang["slogan3"] = "It's a social media. Eh, it's more like a game.",
$lang["slogan4"] = "Fantastic yet fabulous life in a screen.",
$lang["slogan5"] = "Not just poke with one finger, you can duel!",
```

My `controller/index`:

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->session->has_userdata('userid')) redirect('yay/home');
    if (get_cookie('remember_me')!=null) {
        //bla bla bla

        redirect('yay/home');
    } else {
        $this->lang->load('slogan',$this->session->userdata('lang'));
        $data = array();
        $data['lg_slogan'] = array(
            $this->lang->line('slogan1'),
            $this->lang->line('slogan2'),
            $this->lang->line('slogan3'),
            $this->lang->line('slogan4'),
            $this->lang->line('slogan5'),
        );
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }
}
```

$this->session->userdata('lang') ===> 'english'

## Result:

[image: $lang arrays echoed behind the navbar]

$lang arrays echoed behind the navbar. And $lg_slogan[0] not showing

[image: view source in browser]

Where's I do it wrong? Please help.

Comment: Did you include the `<?php ...` tag in `slogan_lang.php` file? It looks like it's getting echoed out before the view is called.

Comment: @ourmandave THAT'S IT!! you're very observant, my bad :'v thanks for the big help!!

Comment: And also the file name should be Slogan_lang.php not slogan_lang.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 no no, I use lower case: `$this->lang->load('slogan', ...);`

Comment: What it recommends https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @wolfgang1983 from official user guide https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html, it says: `Language files must be named with _lang.php as the filename extension. For example, let’s say you want to create a file containing error messages. You might name it: error_lang.php`. They use lower case for example, so I think it's not really matter and is simply a question of what's more convenient to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely my bad because I wasn't so careful ( ... actually because I'm so sleepy, lol). **Anyway, it SOLVED NOW!!**
There's 2 of my mistake:

1. I din't type the opening `<?php` in my slogan_lang.php file
2. I use comma (,) instead of standard delimiter (;)

That's it, sorry & thank you! :")